# How to redirect user to Play Store to download the viewer based on file format?

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play, mime-types

In my application, I have multiple types of documents. I am using the following code.

```
String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(targetFile.getName());
String type = map.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);

Uri targetUri = Uri.fromFile(targetFile);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(targetUri, type);
```

Which opens the supported viewer list and everything works fine.

But when the viewer is not available let us say viewer for TIFF then I want the user to automatically redirect to the Play store with the default search query entered as "Tiff viewer" or like that.

I am able to redirect to the Play Store using the following code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/"));
context.startActivity(intent);
```

However, I don't know how to give the default search criterion based on file format(like TIFF Viewer).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think google play application support such intent action.
But here is a workaround, you can do some homework first, collect some popular file viewers for different format. Then, e.g, if TIFF file viewing action query returns no package on the device, you can start play store with:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse("market://detailsid=com.most.popular.tiffviwer.found"));
startActivity(i);
```